# How to describe experience that is not gained through an employment?

Tags: word-request

I have developed Android Apps for over 5 years now, though the first professional experience I gained is for the past few months only. Is there any word to describe the experience gained through personal projects?

Comment: Is "personal experience" not good enough?

Comment: Should the word / phrase you're looking for also describe the "practical knowledge" of people who know how to, for example, ***cook*** - even if they've never worked as a chef?

Comment: @Jan is it used in such a context? I've always felt personal experience doesn't fit into this.

Comment: @FumbleFingers basically, a word parallel to 'experience', but talking about the experience I gained through personal projects. I'm afraid just using 'experience' will make people think the experience was gained through employment.

Comment: In what context do you intend to use it? Like applying for a programmer job? You can check online about how to write a "CV" as a programmer and you'll see what terms other people use. I can tell you "personal experience" or "hobby experience" is often used as opposed to "professional experience."

Comment: @Jan please do write the same as an answer; it answers my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A programmer who is writing a CV to apply for a new job can mention that he/she has x years of *personal* or *hobby* experience and x months/years of *professional* experience (the later usually means being a part of a programmer group in a company).

If you [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=programmer%20cv%20%22personal%20experience%22%20%22professional%20experience%22&newwindow=1&ei=ObcUXdfGDIrCkwXK_bOAAg&start=0&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwiXx5LG1YnjAhUK4aQKHcr-DCA4ChDy0wMIgwE&biw=1280&bih=918), you can see programmers often mention personal and professional experience in their CVs.